# Unknown state with 74193 IC (PSpice simulation)

Tags: simulation, clock, pspice

I'm trying to design a frequency divider (by 7) in PSpice using a [74193](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74ls193) synchronous 4-bit up/down counter.

When simulating I'm getting the following graph:

[image]

I'm not sure why the state is unknown (where the red lines are), but I think it might have to do with the initial state of the clocks.

The circuit:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of flip-flops is unknown until you do something to force them to a known state. For this IC, only a "Load" or "Clear" will do this. In your circuit, pulsing the Clear input would be the simplest.